# Mobile application test in safari browser

Tags: manual-testing, mobile, cross-browser-testing, mobile-applications

Is there is an open source to check the mobile application in the Safari browser?

Right now am using Responsive Web Design tester Add on chrome but in the add on we have some devices like iPhone and Ipad but it is running under the chrome browser.

During testing the same application in the Responsive Web Design tester is working as we expected but whenever testing in Ipad my test is failed and application is behaving wrongly while displaying the dashboard data

Can anyone please suggest me to any open source tool to check in Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

Safari Browser is widely used in Software testing company for responsive testing of the mobile applications.

In order to test application Responsiveness in Safari Browser there is a option:

> Develop--> Enter Responsive Design Mode.

You need to enable the develop mode in Safari browser first by following below steps

Inorder to enable Develop mode:

> 1. Safari Preferences-->2. Advanced Tab-->3. Check Show Develop menu in menu bar

Answer (score 0):

As a software testing company we recommend to use browser stack tool that will solve all your problems. However that has some free trial period for some time and post that you can go for a license if you prefer.
Another open source url that you can use is https://www.browserling.com/, however it depends when you get access as we need to wait for the turn!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to test your websites/web applications in Safari browser on an iPhone.

For this you can either use the emulators that come with Xcode in a Mac PC or Macbook.

If you don't want to go with that you can use,

[Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/)

[Amazon AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/)

You can also check if people in your team have iPhones. You can request them to lend their phones for you to test.